# Windows Update COMPLETE history

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-update

I've looking some time for a script that can be used to export a full history of installed updates on a Windows System.

I have alredy tried some community solutions like:

- wmic qfe list
- Get-Hotfixes
- PSWindowsUpdate module
- Get-WuaHistory (listed in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626129/how-do-i-get-the-update-history-from-windows-update-in-powershell))
- Systeminfo

I've also seen that you can view a list of installed updates in the appwiz.cpl, but I haven't been able to get anywhere near that information.

I need a list that shows not only the latest updates on the system, but all updates since the SO was installed, including hidden updates.

I also need to list all the updates that have come from the Windows Update service, not just the system related ones (Office and software that is also installed on the system).

I also need the script to work offline as it is intended to run on multiple systems and not all of them are connected to the internet.

At this point I don't even know if this is possible. Please help!

Comment: You're not going to find it. There was a windows update that broke things, but what it also did was clean the history, and yes, it was not an upgrade. But it made it impossible to remove that update as well. If it happened once, it probably happens more often. Also a windows upgrade will refresh windows to a completely new subsystem, removing all updates too. They are irrelevant at that point anyway.

Comment: You have already exhausted all the known methods.

Comment: Note, for example., how `Dism.exe ... /ResetBase` completely destroys update history, preventing rollback: http://www.edtittel.com/blog/wed-dism-resetbase-bites-back.html . If you **must** have the complete Windows update history, the only way to get that would be to install Windows 10 again, and record the state after *each* update, lest, as @LPChip states, one of those updates *deletes* history!

Comment: Can you make use of:
`$Searcher = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Searcher
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher();
$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount())  | ogv`